# Creating an xPath to select a <p> element that has a <h3> preceding it

Tags: jquery, html, xpath

I'm looking to create an xpath that will target specific h3 titles on a page contained within the structure below, then select the sibling p tag that comes after:

```
<ul>
  <li> Title A
    <h3> Message A
    <p> Number A
  </li>
  <li> Title B
    <h3> Message B
    <p> Number B
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to only select the p element if its preceding element is a h3 and matches a specific string.

I've come up with this so far:

```
/ul/li/h3[.="TELEPHONE:"]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Appreciate any advice why it may not be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close `<h3>` tag and `<p>` tags

If I rewrite your example like that

```
<ul>
  <li>Title A
    <h3>Message A</h3>
    <p>Number A</p>
  </li>
  <li>Title B
    <h3>Message B</h3>
    <p>Number B</p>
  </li>
  <li>Title C
    <h3>Message C</h3>
    <p>Number C</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can search what you need like

```
//li/h3[contains(text(), 'Message A')]/following-sibling::p
```